# C++ Windows Not Getting Any Messages

Tags: c++, windows, message

I am creating a simple window but when I see the window being created and closes it, not WM_QUIT message is ever gotten. Here's some code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    cWindowApplication app(hInstance);

    const long width = 1024L;
    const long height = 768L;

    if (app.CreateWindowApplication(width, height) == false)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to create OpenGL Window", "An error occurred", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        app.DestroyWindowApplication();
        return 1;
    }

    return app.MainLoop();
}
```

Here's the CreateWindowApplication(int, int) function:

```
bool cWindowApplication::CreateWindowApplication(long width, long height, bool full_screen /*= false*/)
{
    DWORD dwExStyle;    // Window Extended Style
    DWORD dwStyle;      // Window Style

    mWindowRect.left = 0L;          // Set Left Value To 0
    mWindowRect.right = width;      // Set Right Value To Requested Width
    mWindowRect.top = 0L;           // Set Top Value To 0
    mWindowRect.bottom = height;    // Set Bottom Value To Requested Height

    mFullScreen = full_screen;

    // fill out the window class structure
    const char* class_name      = "MyClass";
    mWindowClass.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    mWindowClass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    mWindowClass.lpfnWndProc    = cWindowApplication::StaticWindowsProcessCallback;
    mWindowClass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    mWindowClass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    mWindowClass.hInstance      = mhInstance;
    mWindowClass.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);          // default icon
    mWindowClass.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);              // default arrow
    mWindowClass.hbrBackground  = NULL;                                     // don't need background
    mWindowClass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;                                     // no menu
    mWindowClass.lpszClassName  = class_name;
    mWindowClass.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);              // windows logo small icon

    // register the windows class
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&mWindowClass))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (mFullScreen == true) //If we are Full Screen, we need to change the display mode                             
    {
        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;                           // device mode

        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);

        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width;               // screen width
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;             // screen height
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = BITS_PER_PIXEL;     // bits per pixel
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
        {
            // setting display mode failed, switch to windowed
            MessageBox(NULL, "Display mode failed", NULL, MB_OK);
            mFullScreen = false;
        }
    }

    if (mFullScreen == true)                // Are We Still In Full Screen Mode?
    {
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;        // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle =   WS_POPUP;               // Windows Style
        //ShowCursor(false);                  // Hide Mouse Pointer
    }
    else
    {
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;   // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;                    // Windows Style
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&mWindowRect, dwStyle, false, dwExStyle);     // Adjust Window To True Requested Size

    // class registered, and create our window
    mHWND = CreateWindowEx(NULL,                            // extended style
        class_name,                                         // class name
        "My Windows",                           // application name
        dwStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        0, 0,                                               // x,y coordinate
        mWindowRect.right - mWindowRect.left,
        mWindowRect.bottom - mWindowRect.top,               // width, height
        NULL,                                               // handle to parent
        NULL,                                               // handle to menu
        mhInstance,                                         // application instance
        this);                                              // this pointer to call member functions

    // check if window creation failed (hwnd would equal NULL)
    if (mHWND == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    mHDC = GetDC(mHWND);

    ShowWindow(mHWND, SW_SHOW);          // display the window
    UpdateWindow(mHWND);                 // update the window
    return true;
}
```

Basically after this function call, the CreateWindowEx() function will call StaticWindowProcessCallback() that looks like this:

```
LRESULT cWindowApplication::StaticWindowsProcessCallback(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    cWindowApplication* win_app = NULL;

    if (msg == WM_CREATE)
    {
        //Creation event
        //Get the pointer we pass during CreateWindowApplication() call
        win_app = (cWindowApplication*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;

        //Associate window pointer with the hwnd for the other events to access
        SetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)win_app);
    }
    else
    {
        //Non-creation event
        win_app = (cWindowApplication*)GetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

        if (win_app != NULL)
        {
            return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    //call member
    return win_app->WindowsProcessCallback(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Finally, the last line of this function calls the member function WindowProcessCallback() that looks like this:

```
LRESULT cWindowApplication::WindowsProcessCallback(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        mHDC = GetDC(wnd);
        SetupPixelFormat();
        //Set the version that we want, in this case 3.0
        int attribs[] = { WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3, WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0, 0 };  //zero indicates the end of the array
        //Create temporary context so we can get a pointer to the function
        HGLRC tmp_context = wglCreateContext(mHDC);
        //Make it current
        wglMakeCurrent(mHDC, tmp_context);

        PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = NULL;
        wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");

        if (wglCreateContextAttribsARB == NULL)
        {
            //No OpenGL 3.0, back to 2.0
            mHGLRC = tmp_context;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create OpenGL 3.0
            mHGLRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(mHDC, 0, attribs);
            //Delete the temp context
            wglDeleteContext(tmp_context);
        }

        //Make OpenGL 3.0
        wglMakeCurrent(mHDC, mHGLRC);
        mIsRunning = true;
    }
        break;
    case WM_QUIT:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    case WM_CLOSE:
        wglMakeCurrent(mHDC, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(mHGLRC);
        mIsRunning = false;
        PostQuitMessage(0); //Send a WM_QUIT message
        return 0;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

As you can see, there are some message processing code there ... but other than the WM_CREATE, no other cases are being hit. After the WM_CREATE message being sent, the function MainLoop() is being called that looks like this:

```
int cWindowApplication::MainLoop()
{
    while (mIsRunning == true)
    {
        ProcessWindowsMessages();
    }

    DestroyWindowApplication();
    return 0;
}
```

Basically the ProcessWindowsMessages() function does not get any message after the window closes ... I have to press stop VS from running in order to kill the process. The ProcessWindowsMessages() function looks like this:

```
void cWindowApplication::ProcessWindowsMessages()
{
    MSG msg;

    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you should have been able to find this with a debugger, if it you knew how it was supposed to behave.  When you bring in third-party code, make sure you understand it.

Comment: If that's the case, there is no need for this site.

Comment: You might read some of the FAQs.  This site isn't supposed to be for debugging help.  The problem with your question is that even if someone in the future had the exact same problem, they wouldn't be able to find your question and my solution.  (Not your fault; I can't think of a good title or search terms either)

Comment: Okay, I will try my best. It's just hard when you have tried debugging for a few days in a row and still don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Anyway, glad it is now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic in `StaticWindowsProcessCallback` looks backwards:

```
    if (win_app != NULL)
    {
        return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

If you don't have a pointer to the window wrapper object, you'll need to call `DefWindowProc`.  So that should happen `if (win_app == NULL)`.  This is to handle a handful of messages that are sent before `WM_CREATE`.  As a  result of this, your code has undefined behavior on messages processed before `WM_CREATE`, and discards (by applying default processing) all messages after `WM_CREATE`.

It would be even better to use `WM_NCCREATE` for setting up the link, though.  As well, `win_app` is not a very good name for this, maybe `win_obj` or something.

You also shouldn't handle `WM_QUIT` in your window procedure, since it isn't sent to a window.  And the default behavior of `WM_CLOSE` should be fine, it will call `DestroyWindow` which will trigger `WM_DESTROY`.

But the first, failure to forward any messages after `WM_CREATE` to your window procedure, likely explains your lack of `WM_QUIT` in the main message loop.

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything. I was looking at code from another source and they had if(!win_app) ... I translated that incorrectly.